# What Melodies can i play to my Mountain?

Tags: mountain

I recently purchased The Mountain, one of the most discussed <strike>screensaver</strike> game in this year.
One of the possible interactions consists of playing Melodies with your keyboard to your Mountain (or are you the Mountain and you are playing to yourself?).

What Melodies can you play and what are their effects?

Comment: I suggest placing the melodies you found (online) in an answer yourself, that way, the question and answer are properly separate. People can then post other answers to add to yours. Or you can make a community wiki post where everyone can insert their answers in.

Comment: I need 10 reputation to create a wiki from the answer ;)

Comment: Then just leave it as your own answer for now, as long as noone else edits new things in, it is *your* answer, and you deserve the rep that comes with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officially Mentioned on the steam page:

- Name: keys-that-have-to-be-pressed (effect)
- Blood mode: mmmmmm,mnab (start rain of blood)
- Snowglobe mode: bbbbbcb (starts snowing)
- Fish: cxzxccc xxx cbb (starts raining fish)

Mentioned from users on the steam page:

- Coins: ccc ccc cbzxc (starts raining coins)
- Frogs: bbaassa ,,mmnnb (start raining frogs)
- Flames: cvbnmbm (start raining balls of fire)
- Hearts: ssfssfsfjhggf (start raining hearts)
- Annihilation: as,zb (mountain is destroyed by alien energy ball and game ends)
- Clear all items: sss, aaam (reset mountain to start)

Once any raining object has been activated, it can be deactivated by clicking on the + icon below the options (thx NexusJob)

Comment: You've got what songs you can play, but you don't add in any of the effects you get from it.  Might be a good idea to add in at least a short description of what each does.

Comment: @Frank better late than never ;) (still not enough rep to turn it into a wiki xD)

Comment: Coins is from Jingle Bells, Frogs from Twinkle, Twinkle Little Star (or, to stay in the holiday mood: Morgen kommt der Weihnachtsmann, which has the same melody). Would be interesting from which songs the rest of the codes are taken.

Answer (score 0):

Blood mode: rain of blood
Snowglobe mode: starts snowing
Fish: starts raining fish
Coins: starts raining coins
Frogs: rains frogs
Flames: balls of fire hit the mountain
Hearts: rains hearts
Annihilation: mountain is destroyed by alien energy ball and game ends.
Clear all items: removes all random items which have hit the mountain

Once any raining object has been activated, it can be deactivated by clicking on the + icon below the options

Comment: Okay.  So how do you play those melodies, then?

Comment: They are played by using the combinations listed on the comment I replied to.